# How to execute "confirm" dialog of gnome session manager from Qt application when logout gnome session (without using QSessionManager)

Tags: c++, qt, centos6, gnome, qt4.8

I am developping the application using Qt4.8, on CentOS6.3

Normaly, When I execute "logout" while runnning the application,
As it is, the application terminated and session logs out.
How can I do to suppress this and allow the Gnome session manager to confirm termination,
or to do not allow logout (and application termination) until processing decided by the application is terminated.

For me as a preferred priority are as follow

1. Session manager inquiries about session end
2. Logout processing (session termination processing) is not performed
   until exit on the application side

I tried the following, but none of the intended behavior (deterring logout).
The application terminated as it is with the logout execution.

- Trap SIGHUP and SIGTERM, and run while (1) loop in the signal handler.
- Trap SIGHUP and SIGTERM, and within the signal handler generate a QMessageBox with the meaning of "Do you really want to quit?", and run exec() to stop the progress of main thread of termination process.
- Override the closeEvent() of the application's main widget (QWidget), generate a QMessageBox with the meaning of "Do you really want to quit?", and run exec() to stop the progress of main thread of termination process.

sample code I tried:

```
void Widget::closeEvent(QCloseEvent *event)
{
    int ret = QMessageBox::warning(
                        this,
                        tr("My Application"),
                        tr("Do you want to logout?"),
                        QMessageBox::Save | QMessageBox::Discard | QMessageBox::Cancel);
    QWidget::closeEvent(event);
}
```

I found a information that Qt has a API called QSessionManager, and tried to try it,
QSessionManager and all processes related to it are invalidated in the configureed / builded library,
I could not use it.

Comment: After re-reading your comment on my answer, is it the case that you are looking to implement the functionality provided `QSessionManager` but cannot use `QSessionManager`?

Comment: I can not use `QSessionManager`.
`QSessionManager` seems to be configured / built as empty code class in my library.

Answer (score 1):

You can trigger the GNOME dialog with [`gnome-session-quit`](http://www.unix.com/man-page/centos/1/gnome-session-quit/).  If you want to use the D-Bus API for this, the [source](https://github.com/GNOME/gnome-session/blob/master/tools/gnome-session-quit.c) of the above utility should be able to guide you.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.
What I want to do is not to trigger "logout" by the application.
During application execution, when the user performs a desktop logout operation,Applications are terminated by gnome-session-save.
I want to implement code in the Qt application to prevent that and cause the confirmation dialog of logout continuation to be displayed, or to interrupt the logout processing until the application terminates.
Do I need to access the D-BUS API from the Qt application?